# How was Israel able to build a powerful military within days of the formation of the state?

Tags: military, israel, 1940s, zionism

The State of Israel was formed in [May 14, 1948](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Israel).

I guess the first Arab-Israel war broke out in [the same month of the same year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1948_Arab%E2%80%93Israeli_War).

**Israel won the war decisively.**

The question is not "How did they win the war?"

The question is, "How did they build up their military within days of the inception of the State of Israel?"

**Who helped them to build their Military so quickly?**

**Where did they find military hardware so quickly?**

Comment: Just as India and Pakistan had an army on day 1 of their existence. No state exists without first building an army (except when another state's army assists them first). The army in question was previously the provincial government's (Britain's) army. It became the Israeli army once Israel came into existence.

Comment: @MonsterTruck, Wouldn't the army have been mostly British? I'd have thought that Britain would have pulled out along with their army.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it was mass conscription.

Comment: @Russell The British did leave but the Haganah/IDF/Jewish Brigade etc… (some of which were technically part of the British army before) didn't. They were reorganised into the modern day IDF (Israel Defense Forces).

Comment: @MonsterTruck, but how did the brigades fill up again when all the British left, or were the brigades made mainly up of locals?

Comment: @Russell That you answered --mass conscription. But an army is more than people. The infrastructure existed already.

Comment: @MonsterTruck. I never though of the infrastructure, but now that I do, it does make sense.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Arab-Israeli conflict didn't start in 1948, it has a long history and was particularly intensified after the British government promised Palestine both to its [Arab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McMahon%E2%80%93Hussein_Correspondence) and [Jewish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balfour_Declaration_of_1917) population in the course of World War I. The first armed conflict is apparently assumed to be the [Battle of Tel Hai in 1920](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Tel_Hai).

As a result, while Israel didn't exist before 1948 there was already a number of Jewish paramilitary organizations like [Haganah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haganah), [Irgun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irgun), [Lehi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern_Gang). You can read the details in [Wikipedia's history of the Israel Defense Forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Defense_Forces#History) but the point is: the army didn't come out of nowhere, it was created around existing organizations that came out in the open. Obviously, these were reinforced by a mass conscription once war broke out but there were existing structures available to integrate new arrivals in.

As to the military equipment, there was apparently a lot of it smuggled into the country over the earlier years. France was also an important source of weaponry, at that time it was the only country to sell weapons to Israel (later replaced by the United States).

Comment: "The Battle" of Tel Hai in 1920 is a peculiar choice of wording: 8 killed vs 5 killed... Thus decisive Arab victory! No kidding, everything is in Wikipedia.

Comment: @kubanczyk: Your point posting this non-sense?

Comment: "the conflict didn't start in 1948" - it started closer to 1948BC than 1948AD, for sure!

Comment: @corsiKa: You are wrong.

Comment: @WladimirPalant No part of the world has seen constant conflict in the same way the middle east has, and much of the conflict has been centered around Jerusalem. The first walls were erected in the 17th century BC (hence my comment about being closer to 1948BC than 1948AD) and walls are not erected just for show. The history between the Jewish tribes and surrounding Arab states (depending on your definition of Arab) has been violent for thousands of years.

Comment: Wasn't Czech republic also a source of weapons alongside France? Or was that later on?

Comment: @corsiKa - The main opponents of Jewish tribes at the time weren't Arab states. Arabs didn't reach the area *en masse* till Islamic invasion and conquest of the 7th Century AD, way after Jews were scattered out of the area for most part. Moreover, both Arabs and Islamic states were initially significantly more Jewish-friendly than not, **especially** compared to Christendom.

Comment: @corsiKa - As for the reason why that part of the world saw as much conflict - that happens when you are situated pretty much at the center of major crossroads. Everyone angling for regional or global hegemony must control the area.

Comment: @DVK: I would be very surprised about that - how would the Czech republic trade weapons to Israel without USSR's approval?

Comment: @WladimirPalant - who said it was without approval? Remember that USSR started out VERY pro-Israel, thinking it will be another Socialist Paradize based on who was running things there (yeah, I know it is deeply schitzophrenic relative to Stalin's ideas about jews in 1952/3)

Comment: @WladimirPalant - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arms_shipments_from_Czechoslovakia_to_Israel_1947%E2%80%931949

Comment: @DVK: Why schizofrenic? Very likely the failure of Stalin's plans regarding Israel was the motive for his plans and actions against the Jews in 1952-3.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson That you rather detest the WWII Allies, I have already noticed. But this assertion of yours is pure fiction.

Comment: The last para is not true. Most of the weapons came from Czechoslovakia and they also provided a military airport to store the supplies and to help transport them.

Answer (score 15):

As a matter of fact, the 1948 war actually started on November 30th, 1947 - the day after the UN Partition Resolution, as the Arabs vowed not to accept it. The first phase of the war pitted Palestine Arab irregular warbands against Jewish paramilitary formations - the mainstream Haganah, the more nationalist Irgun, and the really really radical Lehi. The Arabs were largely beaten in this phase. During the second phase, the armies of five regular Arab states invaded the newly formed State of Israel and by and large met with defeat. (The only one of them to acquit itself well was the Transjordanian Arab Legion, a British-trained and partially British-officered unit).

The main brunt of the first phase of the fighting was borne by the Haganah. Where did it come from? Well, for the duration of the British Mandate in Palestine, the Jews were building, with British sanction, the institutions of a proto-state, usually called in later historiography "medina shebaderech", literally meaning Hebrew for "a state on its way". This included democratic elections of quasi-executive and quasi-legislative councils, trade unions, healthcare institutions etc. (Wikipedia is very [brief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Palestine#The_Jewish_Yishuv) on this - but still worth a look). It was also building a paramilitary capacity, known as the [Haganah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haganah) - unlike the rest of the institutions, this was mostly against British wishes. (Haganah-British relations are a somewhat complicated subject, which I haven't time to treat here fully). Haganah was also practicing a form of "voluntary conscription" - young men were expected by their society to join its training for a year; those who declined to do so were socially frowned upon.

So, when the newborn Israel needed an army, it had the nucleus of one - Haganah. This is the story in brief.

One source which treats this from an interesting angle is a chapter in the book [Supreme Command](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1400034043) by E.Cohen.

Answer (score 3):

Actually she wasn't able - the Israeli army of that time was quite far from being mighty. It was a more or less hodge-podge assembly of what they could assemble during the British rule and what they could import just after the British left. The thing is (as other replies pointed out) that the invading Arab armies (with the exception of the Arab Legion from Transjordan) weren't any more mighty, even less so.

During the British era prior to the Independence there was a ban on weapons so what they could smuggle in and hide from the Brits were quite limited in quantity and quality. But even that time there were local conflicts between Arabs and Jews and it was clear that the moment the Brits leave there will be a wide-scale open conflict. So they built up paramilitary militias (like Haganah) which later during the war served as the core of the new army (other replies give a good view on this) and tried to arm themselves: smuggle in weapons and also manufacture them while hiding all of these from the Brits. E.g. they exported civilian airplanes to use in agriculture then secretly converted them to military use - once the Brits left these converted civilian airplanes formed the first batch of the new Israeli Airforce. They manufactured weapons, copying the British arms (like the Stern machinegun https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sten#Palestininian_Mandate_Stens ) or even inventing new types like the Davidka mortar which wasn't really of any use as a mortar but was loud and scary which made it quite useful in scaring the enemy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davidka).
Another preparation for the war was that the Jewish Agency tried to buy up weapons they could get in Europe and in the US. They could buy up a variety of weapons, usually outdated or inferior versions of more modern weapons (like the Czechoslovak Avia S-199  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avia_S-199) but as the enemy wasn't equiped any better it gave the Israelis quite the edge during the war. The Jewish Agency made a deal with Chechoslovakia, purchased arms from them and had them store them in Chechoslovakia. They smuggled in what they could during the British rule and started to transport the rest (like the airplanes) once the British left (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arms_shipments_from_Czechoslovakia_to_Israel_1947%E2%80%9349). This was called Operation Balak (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Balak)

Answer (score 1):

The Israel had a number of paramilitary groups which had been training, stockpiling arms long before the 1948 war, many Jews joined the British forces during ww2 to gain military experience. The Zionists had created a shadow army and had stockpiled weapons for a long time before 1948.

The Local Arab forces were very disorganised divided and had little weaponry by comparison, and their supporters in other Arab states were reluctant to effectively arm them no lest because they were keen to suppress any possible Palestinian state and annex land the could form that state.

The Arab intervention forces were poorly organised and equipped in General and very divided politically. The Arab Legion was pretty well equipped and organised (though not that well supplied with ammunition that had not stockpiled well and the blockade of resupply was much more effective on Arab forces than Zionist forces, who were better able to circumvent the arms embargo during the war and cease fires) Jordan sought to reach an understanding with the Zionist leadership and was primarily focused on annexing much or the proposed Palestinian state rather than attacking the new state of Israel the only real disagreement being Jerusalem. Syrians were involved in a limited land Grab, the Lebanese made a demonstration not an attack, and Iraqi forces were troublemakers shipped off rather than supported army force.

The Syrians used extremely dated pre ww2 French tanks of dubious value. The Israeli forces were not fighting well developed and equipped armies. The Arab states were also fairly new, badly equipped with obsolete weapons operating in many cases a long distances from the logistical bases.

Comment: second paragraph is bogus. There was no concept of "Palestinians" until AFTER the 1948 war, when Jordan and Syria invented the term to unite the Arabs they'd forcibly displaced out of Israel against Israel. The Arab locals in Israel were as well armed as the Israeli locals, mostly with assorted WW1 and WW2 era rifles and pistols. On the Israeli side though, the armed forces had detachments in most towns and Kibutzin in anticipation of an attack and raids by Arab bandits, which helped enormously during the early stages of the conflict.

Comment: Yes there was a concept of Palestinians before 1948. My wife who was born early 1948 in what is now Northern Israel  has Palestine as the place of her birth on her birth certificate.

Comment: "Palestinian" meant "Jew" until 1960-ies, when PLO hijacked the term.

Comment: The various Palestinian Arab Congresses 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestine_Arab_Congress

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filastin_(newspaper)

Comment: @sds Palestinian meant people living in the British Mandate for Palestine - regardless wether they were Jews, Arabs or whatever.